# What is the word for a plant covered in fine white hairs?

Tags: single-word-requests, plant-physiology

There are some plants whose leaves and stems are not the usual glossy green, but which are covered in very fine white hairs, or white fuzz. One example I have right now in my kitchen would be sage.

[image]

I am sure that there is a word in the English language which describes the appearance of such plants (not just fuzzy plants, but specifically ones covered in white fuzz). But I don't remember the word. Does someone know it?

Comment: Is there an equivalent word in another language you can think of?

Comment: No, I only have ever read it in English. I remember looking it up in a dictionary and being amazed at the existence of such a specific word.

Comment: Dusty or mouldy ;)

Comment: @mplungjan I am enough of a hobby cook for my hair to stand on end when I hear such talk of my herbs. Let's call the ones on the back shelves "secondary canescent" instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try *[hoary](http://www.wordnik.com/words/hoary)*, *[canescent](http://www.wordnik.com/words/canescent)*, or *[incanous](http://www.wordnik.com/words/incanous)*.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! It was "canescent" I was looking for, didn't know the others. How did you find them so quick, did you know them or is there some kind of reverse dictionary available where I could put a description and get the word?

Comment: I knew *hoary* and *canescent* so I just googled those words and added *incanous* to the list. But you can use a reverse dictionary as well. A search of "reverse dictionary" will turn up several serviceable ones.

Answer (score 5):

[Pubescence](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pubescence) is the term used for plants.

> *Botany & Zoology* soft down on the leaves and stems of plants or on various parts of animals, especially insects.

Comment: Whilst you are technically correct (assuming that by 'the term used for plants' you mean 'the term used for the hairiness/fuzziness of plants'), the OP asked specifically for fine *white* hairs, not hairs in general (hence my downvote).

Comment: adj. [puberelent](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/puberulent) *covered with fine soft hairs or down*

Answer (score 3):

'Pubescent' is technically correct.
"Hairy" is actually used in some botanical texts, although of course plants do not have hair as in the mammalian sense. 
Also "downy" -- fine white hairs on leaves. 
Another scientific term is sericeous" -- silky with dense appressed hairs.

Answer (score 3):

Trichome,  meaning "hair", are fine outgrowths or appendages on plants, algae, lichens, and certain protists. They are of diverse structure and function. Examples are hairs, glandular hairs, scales, and papillae. - **[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichome)**

Comment: Good answer. The defining adjectives are listed on the listed website. They are definitely technical and usually, the leaves of such plants are simply called "hairy."

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly be looking for the world "Pilose", my best guess as it's used in the sphere of botany quite a bit.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please improve your answer by adding links to references to the word you're suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

Just to round things out - **lanate**

> : covered with fine hair or hairlike filaments : woolly

"Lanate." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 27 Dec. 2017.

> Lamb's-ear plants are perennial herbs usually densely covered with gray or silver-white, silky-**lanate** hairs. They are named lamb's ears because of the leaves curved shape and white, soft, fur-like hair coating.

Stachys byzantina: Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stachys_byzantina